# SAP Connector 3.0 and Consume Adapter Service

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, sap-dotnet-connector

I have configured my developer machine and trying to develop a new project with SAP.

I have already installed:

```
 1. BizTalk Adapter Pack 2016 
 2. WCF LOB Adapter SDK 
 3. SAP .NET Connector 3.0 x64 .NET 4.0
```

But when I am trying in Visual Studio to Consume Adapter Service with "sapBinding" I receive the following error:

> Connecting to the LOB system has failed.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPGInvoker.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .Net Connector for SAP make sure to change the connectorType to NCo

[image]

Comment: ...but my problem is on design time ... with Visual Studio, not with BizTalk.

Comment: yes this is during adapter service configuration in Binding Properties

Answer (score 2):

From [Install the BizTalk Adapter Pack 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/installing-the-biztalk-adapter-pack-2016)

> Because both Visual Studio and BizTalk MMC are 32-bit processes, you must install the 32-bit BizTalk Adapter Pack on the computer where you complete the design-time tasks.

So install both the 32bit and 64bit versions.